# Diophantine equation got wrong

Tags: diophantine-equations

I am trying to understand [Diophantine equation](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diophantine_equation) article in wiki. They say that in the given equation:

$$ax + by = c$$

There will be such integers $x,y$ **if and only if** $c$ is a multiplier of  greatest common divisor of $a$ and $b$.

So how does this example lay out with that rule?

$3*3 + 2*4 = 17$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here you have $a=3, b=2$.  The greatest common divisor of $3$ and $2$ is $1$.   $17$ is a multiple of $1$, so there is a solution to the equation, namely that $x=3, y=4$.

Answer (score 0):

It does in fact verify the statement, because $$\mathrm{gcd}(3,2) = \mathrm{gcd}(3,4) = 1$$